# How can I get the line count of a text file?

Tags: windows-7, search, parsing

I don't want it to delete the rest or anything but just to quickly report the number of lines the text I just entered is included.

How can I quickly find "the number of lines in this text that include the string I just entered"?

Comment: Please specify how your question is different from a text editor? Most text editors show the current line and thus allow you to how many lines the document has.

Comment: This is useful when files are large enough that they cannot or should not be loaded into memory.  In a *nix world, I would go to `wc` to do this, which reads files as streaming input (and stdin).  The `find` solution below is similar.  A text editor would read the entire file contents to memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best option was a **cat text |grep text|wc -l** with an msys installation.

Comment: If you have `grep`, then an even better option would be `grep PATTERN FILE | wc -l` or, even better, `grep -c PATTERN FILE`.

Comment: This looks like an [Useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 7):

In `notepad`, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to view current line number.
It also at bottom-right corner of status-bar.

Comment: Weird. There's no status bar (greyed out in drop down menu) here. Windows 7.

Comment: `Status bar` will disabled if you wrap lines. Notepad cannot calculate the line number.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done natively in Windows, using the command prompt:

```
find /c "string to find" "mytextfile.txt"
```

---

`findstr` is more advanced (supports regex) but doesn't support printing line count. You could pipe its output to `find`:

```
findstr "string to find" "mytextfile.txt" | find /c /v ""
```

`find /c /v` means count lines not containing. From testing, the empty string to find (`""`) never actually occurs in the piped input from `findstr`, so its a safe value to use.

Answer (score -1):

If you copy and paste the text into word you can see the Words, Characters (with and without spaces), Paragraphs and Lines by clicking on the bottom left where it shows the word count preview.

Comment: It's unclear which program you are refering to. As the questioner didn't specify any program.