# How can I count the line breaks in a folder recursively?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to learn a native command line method of counting lines of code in any project saved on Windows.

That way, no matter where I'm working or what language / IDE I'm working with, knowing how big the project is can be achieved with a command.

Assuming I want to target a specific file extension in the target directory (and all sub directories) what might be an effective way to recursively count the number of line breaks within a folder (and sub folders) from the Windows command line?

Comment: will you accept Powershell answers?

Comment: @rob sure, go ahead.

Comment: you wish to accumulate a total, so while deciding which files to process may be recursive, the processing of each file must be iterative. I would probably build a tree of files recursively, and use a visitor implementation to accumulate the line count.

Comment: You could also do this from WSH or from Node.JS (which you could also very easily use to create an executable (with or without a UI) using node-webkit. JavaScript rules! Well kind-of :}

Comment: Why not use a proper tool to gather metrics (and maybe do some static code analysis while you are at it).  I am guessing that you are only looking  for a rough indicator, as you don't seem to have considered whether blank lines / comments should be counted. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code

Comment: Oh, yes, and what do you about lines like `printf("New paragraph follows:\n\n\");`? How many lines is that?  ;-)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/407948/what-tool-can-produce-the-line-count-of-a-text

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I count the number of lines in files in a folder recursively?

Use the following batch file (countlines.cmd)

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b /s %1`)  do (
  echo processing file %%a
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`type %%a ^| find "" /v /c`) do (
    echo line count is %%b
    set /a lines += %%b
    )
  )
echo total lines is %lines%
```

Notes:

- Total number of lines is stored in `%lines%`.
- remove `echo ...` as appropriate for silent running.

Usage:

```
countlines filename_expression
```

Example:

```
countlines *.java
```

will output the following:

```
processing file F:\projects\test\foo.java
line count is 10
processing file F:\projects\test\test.java
line count is 106
processing file F:\projects\test\Wheel4Applet.java
line count is 350
total lines is 466
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the total line count from windows command line

```dos
(for /r "c:\somewhere" %a in (*.c) do @type "%a")|find /c /v ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count all the lines as Powershell defines lines in MyTargetPath

```
Get-Content (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path MyTargetPAth -file).FullName | measure -line
```

Just setup MyTargetPath first.

Comment: I haven't used powershell, could you explain 'setup MyTargetPath'?

Comment: just replace MyTargetPath with what ever path you want, optional in double quotes. or change my code to use $MyTargetPath and run $MyTargetPath="path required" to set it.

Comment: Ah yeah, I looked up how to set a variable and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider a tool? (And are you aware of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?)

I use [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sloccount/?source=directory) (although it might not work for web development):

> SLOCCount is an easy-to-use tool that counts Source Lines of Code
>   (SLOC). It auto-determines the language(s) (inc. C, C++, Ada,
>   Assembly, shell, COBOL, C#, Fortran, Haskell, Java, LISP/Scheme, Perl,
>   PHP, Python, Ruby, SQL). It also estimates cost & time.

Linux has a word & line counter & there is a Widows implementation [here](http://www.tawbaware.com/wc.htm).

Or, use `findstr /R /N "^" file.txt` (more on [this page](http://brett.batie.com/scripting/count-number-of-lines-in-a-file-using-dos/)).

Or, ou might find your answer on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/407948/what-tool-can-produce-the-line-count-of-a-text) extremely similar SuperUser question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with very large files there is a considerable performance gain if you use file redirection versus using the PIPE. Testing with a 437MB file that had 8,895,540 lines. Piping to the find command took 14.6 seconds. Using redirection it only took 5.4 seconds.  If you are counting smaller files the difference of course would be negligible.

```
@echo off
set "lines=0"
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b /s %1`)  do (
  echo processing file %%a
  for /f %%b in ('find /V /C "" ^<"%%a"') do (
    echo line count is %%b
    set /a lines+=%%b
    )
  )
echo total lines is %lines%
```